# How to create a horizontal bar that stretches across screen but is not in the body tag?

Tags: css, background, repeat

Very basic question!

I have a background pattern that repeats itself throughout the body tag.  I would also like to have a top bar and bottom bar (head/footer) to repeat on the x axis - creating a nice sandwich style of solid color, pattern and solid color again for the background.

How can this be accomplished?

The bars need to be 100% width - which is why this isn't being done through the content wrapper or the header/footer div as they are set to 1000px wide.  The color bars should go across the entire screen.

Answer (score 6):

You should:

- Ensure you have `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`
- Add the `#headerBar` and `#footerBar` outside of your "content wrapper".

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#contentWrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100px
}
#headerBar {
    height: 40px;
    background: blue
}
#footerBar {
    height: 40px;
    background: red
}
```

Or if you would like the bars to stick to the viewport and be behind content: http://jsfiddle.net/GDDA5/3/

Comment: The header works - my problem is the footer.  The footer bar is forced down under the actual content.  What I want to do is to continue it horizontally- behind the content. I was wondering if some sort of positioning or z-index trick was needed.

Comment: @Tigger: Did you check the second jsFiddle link in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did - thank you for that answer as well.  I am looking for an answer that is viewport independent.  Here is a site that has the header and footer with the same design I am trying to achieve. http://www.mwatoday.com/initiatives/mwa_grant_program.aspx

Comment: After reviewing the CSS - I see how they achieved the footer. The blue footer color is actually the body color and then the content wrapper is white - creating the sandwich look. On my site - the body background is a pattern and the content wrapper has its own background so it doesn't work for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

i'm late to the parity here, but use css3!

```
#selector:after { content: '|' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take the footer div out of the content wrapper div, then it should take the body width dimensions automatically, giving you the effect you are looking for.